# Using both LaTeX Notation and `.format()` when creating a plot title

Tags: python, matplotlib, formatting, latex

So I am making a plot with matplotlib and I would like to have an index in a variable name in the title, while I am also using `.format()` to insert a variable. For instance:

```py
V_set = 10
x = np.arange(0,10) #arbitrary data

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,x)
plt.title('V$_{set}$: {}'.format(V_set))
plt.show()
```

The code does not work as it is looking for the key `set` which obviously does not exist.

I guess I could make it work like this:

```py
V_set = 10
x = np.arange(0,10) #arbitrary data

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,x)
plt.title('V$_{set}$:'+str(V_set))
plt.show()
```

But I would prefer to use `.format()`. Any suggestions? Or does anyone know if that is possible?
Any help or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I just found the answer myself. When using double brackets the values are ignored, for anyone running into the same problem.

```py
V_set = 10
x = np.arange(0,10) #arbitrary data

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,x)
plt.title('V$_{{set}}$: {}'.format(V_set))
plt.show()
```